# How to get the xml contents without using the while loop

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file which contains two start tags and end tags. And I need the contents within these two tags separately. Please check the below content.

```
<testing>
  <test>
  <text>test1</text>
  </test>
  <test>
  <text>test2</text>
  </test>   
</testing>
```

As of now I am using a while loop and finding the start index and end index of the tags and then getting the contents using the substring method. Please check the below code.

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\testing_doc.txt");
int startindex = xml.IndexOf("<test>");
while (startindex > 0)
{
  int endIndex = xml.IndexOf("</test>", startindex);
  int length = endIndex - startindex;
  string textValue = xml.Substring(startindex, length);
  startindex = xml.IndexOf("<test>", endIndex); // getting the start index for the second test tag
}
```

Is there any other way to get the contents without using the while loop? Because using while seems to be kind of expensive and if text file is corrupted then it will cause other problems.

Thanks in advance,
Anish

Comment: You could use a regular expression to parse all the string in just one instruction, but you should consider taking a different approach altogether and use built int XML related classes, those would be more trustworthy and probably easier to use.

Comment: "if text file is corrupted then it will cause other problems". IMHO if file is corrupted you should not try to read it, if it is corrupted, how can you be sure its data is fine?

Comment: Why is a while loop expensive?

Comment: If it is an xml file, why does it have .txt extension? I know, I am nitpicky here, but that would raise a red flag in _my_ head ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [XPATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) which is designed to solve querying XML as the following:

```
var xml = @"<testing>
  <test>
  <text>test1</text>
  </test>
  <test>
  <text>test2</text>
  </test>   
</testing>
";

var testing = XElement.Parse(xml);
var tests = testing.XPathEvaluate("test/text/text()") as IEnumerable;
foreach (var test in tests)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test); // test1, test2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `XmlDocument` class which is based on W3C DOM(Document object Model)
 and `XPath` class
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

```
doc.load(@"C:\testing_doc.txt");

XmlNodeList values = doc.SelectNodes("testing/test/text");  //Using XPath

string str = string.Empty;

    foreach (XmlNode x in values)
    {
        str += x.InnerText + ",";
    }

str.TrimEnd(',');

Console.WriteLine(str);   //test1,test2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do manually, regex can help you

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\testing_doc.txt");
string pattern = "<test>(.*?)</test>";
Match match = Regex.Match(xml , pattern);
if (match.Success){
    System.Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

But think about the library helping to parse XML available [XMLDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) or [LinQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml)